# DeliveryNotificationOptions won't work on gmail and hotmail

Tags: c#

I am using SmtpClient to send a message through a gmail account, I set DeliveryNotificationOptions to DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess, the message sent ok, but there is no delivery notifiacton. I also tried hotmail, still no delivery notification. However the same code works fine on outlook exchange server.

any ideas? Cheers
Harry

Comment: Does hotmail and gmail support delivery notifications?

Comment: Hi w69rdy, I don't know, assume they support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no gaurantee that any mail server will support this option, you cannot count on it at all. If hotmail and gmail respected this can you imaging how useful it would be to spammers.

Comment: Thanks Ben, Is there any way I can get a delivery notification for gmail?

Comment: There is no way to ever know for sure whether an email has been delivered anywhere, spammers have been trying to crack this for years. The best bet is to assume that if you do not receive an NDR from the mail server then it has been delivered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Hotmail, but Gmail definitely doesn't support delivery notifications:

[Read receipts in Gmail](http://knol.google.com/k/read-receipts-in-gmail)

Comment: Hi Sean, Gamil doesn't support read receipts, but does it support delivery receipts? I just want to know whether the message is sent out successfully or not? Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The link has died. Perhaps https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9413651?hl=en points to the same resource?